# My javascript works on firebox but not on chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following code

```js
//followers list
document.getElementById('followers').onchange = function(evt) {
  try {
    let files = evt.target.files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('No file selected!');
      return;
    }
    let file = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    const self = this;
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      obj = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
      followers_data = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        return obj[key];
      });
      followers = followers_data.flat(1);

      follower_array = [];
      for (i = 0; i < followers.length; i++) {
        follower_array.push(followers[i].string_list_data[0].href);
      }
      document.getElementById('followers_result').value = follower_array.join("\n");
      followers = document.getElementById('followers_result').value;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

//following list
document.getElementById('following').onchange = function(evt) {
  try {
    let files = evt.target.files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('No file selected!');
      return;
    }
    let file = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    const self = this;
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      obj = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
      followers_data = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        return obj[key];
      });
      followers = followers_data.flat(1);

      follower_array = [];
      for (i = 0; i < followers.length; i++) {
        follower_array.push(followers[i].string_list_data[0].href);
      }
      document.getElementById('following_result').value = follower_array.join("\n");
      // console.log(document.getElementById('followers_result').value);
      following = document.getElementById('followers_result').value;


    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

following = document.getElementById('following_result').value;
console.log(following);
followingj = JSON.stringify(following);
spfollowing = JSON.parse(followingj);
finalfollowing = spfollowing.split('\n');
console.log(finalfollowing);

followers = document.getElementById('followers_result').value;
console.log(followers);
followersj = JSON.stringify(followers);
spfollowers = JSON.parse(followersj);
finalfollowers = spfollowers.split('\n');
console.log(finalfollowers);

finalfollowing = finalfollowing.filter(val => !finalfollowers.includes(val));
users = [];
finalfollowing.forEach(function(item) {
  user = item.split('https://www.instagram.com/');
  users.push(user[1]);
})

console.log(users);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Followers and Following List Comparison</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css" />  -->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="follows">
    <div class="followers">
      <h2>Upload Followers List</h2>
      <input id="followers" type="file" accept="application/json" />
      <textarea id="followers_result" rows=25 cols=50></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="following">
      <h2>Upload Following List</h2>
      <input id="following" type="file" accept="application/json" />
      <textarea id="following_result" rows=25 cols=50></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="result">
      <h2>People who are not following you</h2>
      <textarea id="result" rows=25 cols=50></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am uploading json files and comparing the files for those that dont follow me. When I use it on firefox, refreshing the page populates the result in the textarea but when i do it on chrome it doesnt work. I also tried to create a function (onchange) where when the file was uploaded, it would do something because i thought it was an issue with the text not displaying bc it wasnt uploaded first but that didnt work. any help would be appreciated pls.

Comment: Do you see any errors in Chrome's console?

Comment: no i only have empty strings @RAllen

Comment: i reduced the amount of code @MichaelM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior in Firefox - it reinstates form elements' content if you refresh the page as did [Netscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_(web_browser)) from which code base it was developed. Other browsers never copied the behavior, whether for legal or other unknown reasons, so refreshing the page will leave form elements blank.

If you want to force Firefox to behave like other browsers, either

- Press `SHIFT` whilst clicking the reload button or simultaneanly pressing `CTRL SHIFT R` instead of `CTRL R` to perform the reload. This is somewhat documented under [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#parameters) within the `location.reload` article on MDN. Or
- Add an `autocomplete="off"` attribute to a `form` or form elements in HTML.

In the HTML standard, reloading a page can take into account its [document state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#document-state-2) which can include [session history entries](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#session-history-entry), which them can include data for [persisted user state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#session-history-entries)
, which is [implementation defined](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#implementation-defined). My understanding of this is that both Firefox's and other browser's behavior comply with the standard.

Saving element data in session storage across reloads, along with code to check for stored data and the absence of it in a reloaded document may be required to implement Firefox's behavior in other browsers. If it's important during *development*, use Firefox as your go to browser.